How to make <thead> and <tbody> rows occupy proportional heights in a table
export const SimpleTable = () => {
  const employees = [
    { name: "John Doe", position: "Manager", employed: "23/04/18" },
    { name: "Alex Nar", position: "Producer", employed: "23/04/18" },
    { name: "Jane Smith", position: "Designer", employed: "12/11/20" }
  ]

  return (
    <div className="w-1/2 h-1/2 overflow-scroll">
      <table className="w-full h-full table-auto border border-gray-400">
        <thead>
          <tr className="h-[10%]">
            <th className="border border-gray-400">Name</th>
            <th className="border border-gray-400">Position</th>
            <th className="border border-gray-400">Employed</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {employees.map((employee, index) => (
            <tr key={index} className="h-[10%]">
              <td className="border border-gray-400">{employee.name}</td>
              <td className="border border-gray-400">{employee.position}</td>
              <td className="border border-gray-400">{employee.employed}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

Why does setting h-[10%] on <tr> elements within both <thead> and <tbody> using Tailwind CSS fail to make the rows occupy 10% of the table's total height, and what is the correct way to ensure each row consistently fills 10% of the table height without stretching?

Make sure that the table has 10 rows. That way the will have 10% of the height each (some exceptions apply). Otherwise, the rows will expand to occupy the full height of the parent, and they will not have a 10% height (unless there are 10). Take into account the code from the question: there are only 4 rows, what is the expected behavior? If you set a 10% height, they would occupy 40% of the table, but that's not possible, it must be 100%. And what happen if there are 50 rows? They cannot occupy 500% of the table.
